# Creating a table with column headers and lining up the values

Tags: java, alignment

I am trying to print out a table without using JTable or any other table functions (just as text).  So far I am able to print out the values, but can't seem to get them to line up correctly.  I'm trying to use tabs but some values are longer than others which makes it difficult. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
package costisnoobjectfinalproject;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CostIsNoObjectFinalProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String customerName;
        String carCode;
        int numOfDays;
        Scanner response = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        String[] columnHeaders = {"Description", "Daily Fee", "Code"};
        String[] cars = {"1967 Ford Mustang", "1922 Ford Model T", "2008 Lincoln Continental", "2002 Lexus", "2007 BMW", "1910 Mercer Runabout", "2009 Mercedes Benz", "1930 Cadillac V-16"};
        double[] dailyFee = {65.0, 95.0, 135.0, 140.0, 160.0, 165.0, 200.0, 205.0};
        String[] carType = {"A", "A", "L", "L", "L", "A", "L", "A"};
        boolean[] alreadyRented = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Antique/Luxury Car Lot! First, let's start with some information.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
            customerName = response.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Thank you. Which kind of car would you like to rent? (L for luxury, A for Antique): ");
            carCode = response.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many days did you want to rent this car?: ");
            numOfDays = response.nextInt();

        for(int count = 0; count < cars.length ; count++) {
            System.out.println(cars[count] + "\t\t" + money.format(dailyFee[count]) + "\t" + carType[count] + "\t" + alreadyRented[count]);
        } //end for
    } // end main

} // end class
```

This code gives a result that looks like this:

```
1967 Ford Mustang       $65.00  A   false
1922 Ford Model T       $95.00  A   false
2008 Lincoln Continental        $135.00 L   false
2002 Lexus      $140.00 L   false
2007 BMW        $160.00 L   false
1910 Mercer Runabout        $165.00 A   false
2009 Mercedes Benz      $200.00 L   false
1930 Cadillac V-16      $205.00 A   false
```

Comment: Keep in mind I still am not sure how to print the columnHeaders array to say something like: Description       Daily Fee      Code         Rental Status

Comment: If you play with tabs (`\t`) you should be able to get alignment for your particular sample data.

Comment: Because I am looping the \t tab code it will always be off because of the varying lengths of the descriptions

Comment: Another option is to use [`printf()`](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/introduction.htm) but you will still need to know the maximum widths of your fields.

Comment: Can you go further into depth how I could use printf() ?

Comment: Have you looked at the link I provided yet?

Answer (score 0):

The tabs in your out put are causing the columns the misalignment.  The longer text values are pushing the next column to the later Tab Stops.

What I typically do:

1. Find the string with the most characters in each column
2. Pad each string with enough spaces to match the max number of characters for its respective column (including the header row strings)
3. Once all padded to the same length print the rows as you did and the stars, er columns will align

The padding will take the place of the tabs and you can separate the columns with only one character if your like

To left justify a column pad on the end of the string, to right justify pad the beginning, to center split the padding between the beginning and the end.

To print the padded headers just put a print before entering the for loop using the same format string as you do in the loop